# Where is my lock file? mysql

Tags: installation, mysql, lock

Below is my console out put I have no idea how to proceed with this, Can anyone provide some direction?

```
apt-get install mysql-server
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following extra packages will be installed:
      libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
    Suggested packages:
      libipc-sharedcache-perl libterm-readkey-perl tinyca
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
    0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
    E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

Comment: Well it's simple.. `exit` your terminal and try again.. If still it doesn't help then restart your system.. You can also try to kill `apt-get` process by: `sudo pkill apt-get`. Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

After a little probing the thread on this page solved my problem, close this hoe!

[Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/how-do-i-fix-a-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-problem)